# DS4 - BlueTooth will not work natively on Win10, but will work with Steam/DS4Windows

Tags: steam, ps4

I have 2 DS4 controllers I use regularly for PC gaming on Windows 10.

#1 works flawlessly on both wired USB and wireless BlueTooth connections.

#2 works flawless ONLY when wired by USB. BlueTooth has these odd problems I can't figure out:

-It will try to pair over BlueTooth to Win10 (the blue bar will flash regularly as expected). When I click through the Win10 menus to finish the pairing process, it will pair and show up immediately under the 'Game Controllers' menu (joy.cpl) BUT it won't work. The light bar will immediately go out. Clicking 'Properties' will show there's no input being detected for the controller. It's like Windows keeps a handle of the wireless controller but won't actually process its inputs.

-The above issue can be fixed immediately either by using Steam's Playstation Controller Support under Big Picture, or by third party software like DS4Windows. It will read inputs and I'm able to play my PC games with this controller wirelessly. I've recreated this on 2 Windows 10 machines.

I'm wondering if this may be a low battery issue, as I've seen discussions suggesting incompatible chargers/USB cables could somehow "drain" the controllers. However, this doesn't make sense because I can still play wirelessly once I boot Steam or DS4Windows. Maybe something physical on this one controller crapped out over time?

This may be related (discussion of controller feature sets over BlueTooth): [Why does my DualShock 4 connect through micro-usb but not Bluetooth?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360760/why-does-my-dualshock-4-connect-through-micro-usb-but-not-bluetooth)

This is a similar issue, but I'm able to get my weird controller working via Steam or DS4Windows:
[PS4 Controller paired over bluetooth "Connected" but not working](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338164/ps4-controller-paired-over-bluetooth-connected-but-not-working)

I'm able to get it working with third-party software, but curious if anyone had ideas for getting this controller working natively in Win10 over BlueTooth.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the model numbers of the controllers and Bluetooth dongle?

Comment: @Lemon  
Working controller = CUH-ZCT2U (newly bought within the last year).
Odd non-working controller = CUH-ZCT1U (presumably a 1st gen PS4 controller).
BlueTooth Dongle = ASUS USB-BT400 (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DJ83070/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)